# Prove that the sum of two multiples of 3 still a multiple of 3

Tags: discrete-mathematics

If a and b are multiples of 3 and if I add a+b the result will be a multiple of 3.
How can I prove that is true?

First of all I know that multiples of 3 are : 3,6,9,12,15 etc.
I tried to find a counterexample but it did not work because for example 3+6=9, 9+12=21 and so on.
Also I know that Numbers are divisible by 3 if the sum of all the individual digits is divisible by 3.

I tried to use that and I started with:

let a and b be multiples of 3 , then 3a+3b=3n, but I am not sure how to continue,can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Comment: What does it mean to say that $a$ is a multiple of $3$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"let a and b be multiples of 3 , then 3a+3b=3n"

Not quite.  If $a$ is a multiple of $3$ then $a = 3n$ for some integer $n$.  We can skip the variable $a$ altogether and say "a multiple of $3$ is of the form $3n$ for some integer $n$.

So if $3n$ is a multiple of $3$, and $3m$ is a multiple of $3$ then you want to prove that:

To prove:  $3n + 3m$ is a multiple of 3.

And as $3n + 3m = 3(n+m)$ then $3n + 3m$ is a multiple of 3. (As it is $3$ times the integer (n + m).)

....

To be neat and to have style points:

An integer $n$ is a multiple of $3$ if  $n = 3k$ for some integer $k$.

So if $a$ and $b$ are two multiples of 3, then $a = 3n$ and $b = 3m$ for some integers, $n,m$.  Then $a + b = 3n + 3m = 3(n+m)$.  As $n + m$ is an integer, $a + b = 3(n + m)$  is a multiple of 3.

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ and $b$ are multiples of $3$ then there are integers $x,y$ such that $a=3x$ and $b=3y$ (by definition). Then

$a+b=3x+3y=3(x+y)$

The result follows.

Answer (score 3):

You need to start with a definition of "multiple".

Let $a$ be an integer. We call $a$ a multiple of 3 if and only if there is a $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=3k$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be multiples of 3. Therefore there are $k, l \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a=3k$, $b=3l$. We have: $a+b=3(k+l)$. The sum of two integers is a integer, so $a+b$ does conform to our definition of multiple of 3, since $a+b=3(k+l)$.

Comment: Hi, I understood the steps but I did not understand the Natural numbers part. It is really necessary to mentioned it?

Comment: Is the notation the issue? $k\in\mathbb{N}$ means that k is a natural number. It is necessary to demand that, since you can write any number as $3k$ if you place no restriction on $k$. Like $1=3k$ for $k=\frac{1}{3}$. But I'm ready to provide an answer if you didn't understand a certain statement.

Comment: Definitely need to mention integers!  7 = 3*(7/3) so 7 is a multiple of 3?  Nope.  It has to be three times and integer.  Otherwise *all* numbers are multiples of 3.  [x = 3*(x/3)]  (But natural numbers aren't enough as negative values are allowed.)

Comment: Nitpick:  $-6 = 3(-2)$ is a legitimate multiple of 3.  The requirement is that $k \in \mathbb Z$.

Comment: @fleablood: Indeed. The list he gave of multiples of 3 suggested that he was stating it for natural numbers, of course the more general statement is also true, it wanted to keep it simple. But you're right, I should define and proof for integers in general. I'll edit the post.

Comment: One doesn't need to talk about the negative values and you can omit them mentioning them altogether but for honesty one should say a "a multiple is a value that is 3 times an integer".  You can't say "a multiple is a value that ie 3 times a number" but one doesn't have to go into detail or mention why an integer is necessary (it should be intuitively obvious without stating).  But as the OP asked we should point out the 1/3 "loophole" and that it must be closed.